# Trying to show popover when my svg icons are hovered .<el-popover> tag not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to show popover when my  svg icons are hovered .But  tag is not working .Why? Its a vue js code.

This is my code

```
<el-popover
    placement="top-start"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="hover"
    content="hiiiiii">
    <svg-icon  icon-class="bed" class="tx-60 " style="width: 1em;height:1em;                                            
           aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="el-popover" tabindex="0"></svg-icon>
</el-popover>
```

Comment: What framework are you using that provides the `el-popover` element?

Comment: I have edited and properly formatted the code. Also, the title was too big. So, I edited the title to shorter meaningful one.

Comment: [link] (https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover#popover) I am using this framework @CascadiaJS

Answer (score 1):

### Use slot="reference"

use slot="reference" in svg-icon tag

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-popover placement="top-start" title="Title" width="200" trigger="hover" content="hiiiiii">
    <el-button slot="reference" type="text" icon="el-icon-edit" class="floatright"> </el-button>
  </el-popover>
</div>
```